# How to modify part of the Content-Disposition in java rest template client

Tags: java, spring, upload, multipartform-data, resttemplate

I'm struggling with creating valid request to some internal service using java spring. The problem is with proper payload for multipart/form-data boundary.

Environment:
java server -> (rest) http multipart/form-data -> some service

(there is no browser in the middle)

Valid payload should look like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryp8mrQWOb5GiyC90y
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="0000.png"
Content-Type: image/png

[binary data]

------WebKitFormBoundaryp8mrQWOb5GiyC90y--
```

Unfortunately I'm unable to change this "headers" and I'm getting something like this:

```
 --fkGT7CJaQB9-2aa8G1ePv17iHKnWSsd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"
Content-Length: 170096

[binary data]

--fkGT7CJaQB9-2aa8G1ePv17iHKnWSsd--
```

I've searched many stackoverlow questions, but nothing seems to work.
This is what I've done till now (generates above payload):

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> additionalHeaders = new HashMap<>();
String fileMd5 = "tgrlfG0pjblWZB6g1f7j5w=="; //@todo
File file = new File(systemFile.getAbsoluteFileLocation());
Path filePath = Paths.get(systemFile.getAbsoluteFileLocation());
try{
    DiskFileItem fileItem = new DiskFileItem("file", "image/png", false, file.getName(), (int) file.length() , file.getParentFile());
    InputStream input =  new FileInputStream(file);
    OutputStream os = fileItem.getOutputStream();
    int ret = input.read();
    while ( ret != -1 )
    {
        os.write(ret);
        ret = input.read();
    }
    os.flush();
    MultipartFile multipartFile = new CommonsMultipartFile(fileItem);


    MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts =
            new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(multipartFile.getBytes());
    parts.add("files", resource);


    additionalHeaders.put("Content-MD5", Collections.singletonList(fileMd5));
    additionalHeaders.put("Content-Disposition", Collections.singletonList("attachment; filename=\""+systemFile.getFilenameWithExtension()+"\""));
    ResponseEntity<FrpFileServer> responseEntity = formDataRestClient.post(this, parts, FrpFileServer.class, isServerSide, frpToken.getTokenId(), additionalHeaders, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    return responseEntity.getBody();
} catch (IOException e) {
    return null;
}
```

formDataRestClient builds the rest of the request via RestTemplate

```
public <K, T> ResponseEntity<T> post(RestClientInterface reference, K requestClass, Class<T> responseClass, boolean isServerSide, String resourceId, HashMap<String, List<String>> additionalHeaders, MediaType contentType) {
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I've fixed my problem with replacing resource creation with this:

```
ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(multipartFile.getBytes()){
    @Override
    public String getFilename() {
        return systemFile.getFilenameWithExtension();
    }
};
```

Thanks to that, restTemplate handles it's magic in proper way :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one generic REST client which you can use in any java based application or framework, see GIT source of delete method how to load anything in request header where i am passing Authorization- https://github.com/gajeralalji/JAVA-REST-Client/wiki

check source of REST-client.java class and let me know if you are still facing any issue.